# How do I remove a completely failed commit?

Tags: github

I was having issues with my faulty git commands, so I have multiple git commits but not the branches or repository.

git rebase -i HEAD~# doesn't have any of the faulty commit ids on the branches including master.

Is it still possible to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what your situation is, but it sounds like you want to delete some commits, even though they aren't showing up on your branches?

If that's true, that the commits lie outside your branches, they may be on a merge branch which git creates temporarily. This is a branch just like yours, but is not as obvious to find.

Maybe try pasting some of your git status and git branch outputs with a little more info on your situation?